# Amateur question. But could you fix a hole in space-time?

Tags: spacetime

I understand it's impossible. But let's say that space-time gets torn and there is a hole in it. If possible, how would you fix the hole?

Comment: Duct tape works wonders.

Comment: Be nice, guys. People who don't know about physics see this site and expect it is a good place to ask. It should be.

Answer (score 4):

General relativity is a theory of gravity. There is a very common picture of gravity as a distortion in a rubber sheet. The Sun sits on the sheet, causing a depression. The Earth rolls around in the depression.

It is unfortunate that this picture is so popular. While it is easy to understand, it is wrong in many ways. It gives rise to questions like yours.

Here is a video that starts with this picture and comes up with a more complicated but more realistic one. [A new way to visualize General Relativity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wrwgIjBUYVc)

Here is another with more about General Relativity. [What is General Relativity?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYq774z4dws)

To answer your question, spacetime is not a thing like a rubber sheet. There is nothing to tear.

Comment: Thank you, I got taught in school about the sheet diagram so I didn't really question it as a kid. That video was very interesting to watch. Thank you again.